# jsbin produces "Script error. (line 0)" when using console.log("test")

Tags: jsbin

I wrote a one line JS script in jsbin and in the console, it spits out an error.

```
console.log("test");
```

In the console on jibs, it shows:

```
"error"
"Script error. (line 0)"
test
```

Why? Pretty valid piece of code.

Comment: Please share your jsbin

Comment: http://jsbin.com/gumuda/edit?html,js,console - does that help?

Comment: I don't get an error

Comment: It is something to do with Safari - My answer - I will use other browsers - the other 2, Chrome and FireFox - no problem. Weird.

Comment: Just had the same message but in Chrome. I opened the browser's JS dev tools and got more information about the error. Maybe this helps someone...

Answer (score 4):

I believe the problem is with the browser, not Jsbin. I posted this answer in case others experience it.

Comment: Thanks, I was getting this error in Safari...saw your answer, immediately downloaded Firefox, ran the same code, and bingo! No error!

Answer (score 3):

Only need to press the new file in the upper left corner

Comment: Thanks you very much